# Xamarin.iOS 8.0 - PresentViewController Issue

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have created a RootViewController class. In this class, i have events listening for user logging success and then present view controller to login page. It works fine when the application starts because i put RootViewController class to windows.RootViewController property, The issue is - i have a logout button as a bar item on the next page after successfully login. When i click on logout button, i dismiss the current view controller and then try to present the RootViewController again so that RootViewController class can present the login screen back again to the user. But, when i touch the logout button then just white blank screen shows up instead of login page. On the console, it outputs the below warning messages. I just want to  add that it was working fine in iOS 7.0 but after updating Xamarin to iOS 8.0 then i start having this issue.

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. My code for redirecting to login page in the RootViewController has to be in the ViewWillAppear Method. Earlier, I only had this in the ViewDidLoad method. Then, I figured out that ViewDidLoad execute only once in the app load but ViewWillAppear work on evey

Comment: I have same problem can you explain in breif. how you solved problem?